# java se compila pero no muestra nada

Tags: java

mi problema es que java simplemente no ejecuta mi código, al instalar java 11  no me admitía la cmd el comando " **javac** " así que cree la variable de entorno path y se resolvió el problema pero se creo uno nuevo y radica en que cuando quiero compilar un archivo .java con el comando javac se queda cargando y luego termina la ejecución sin mostrar nada, probe incluso el archivo sin ningún código y lo mismo, lo único que muestra es cuando hay algún error en el código :([image: imagen que muestra el error con el comando javac]

Comment: "No news, good news." No te muestra nada porque ha ido bien. Pero la compilación no te ejecuta el programa, solo te genera el programa compilado. Usa "java" para ejecutar el compilado.

Comment: Después de ese comando iría java HolaMundo para mostrar el contenido de tu programa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javac solo complila los .java en .class por lo que javac esta funcionando correctamente lo que te faltaria para ejecutar el programa es correr en la linea de comandos

```
java Holamundo
```

Comment: ahora cuando lo intento me sale este error Error: Main method not found in class Holamundo, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Debes escribir `main` en minúscula todo. Prueba, compila y ejecuta. Comenta los resultados. Saludos