# No se ejecuta nada en consola Java

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero, aleatorio;
        int intentos = 5;
        aleatorio = (short)(100*Math.random()+1);

        do{
            numero = entrada.nextInt();
            if(aleatorio<numero){
               intentos--;
               System.out.println("El numero es mayor"+"Quedan"+intentos);
            }

            else{
                intentos--;
                System.out.println("El numero es menor"+"Quedan"+intentos);}
        }while(numero != aleatorio);

        System.out.println("Ganaste");



            }
        }
```

No se visualiza nada en la consola.
Deberia al menos pedir que ingrese datos, java ni siquiera me lanza un error o algun aviso de que puede estar fallando. Ya revise el codigo y todo parece estar bien. Soy nuevo programando en java.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [java se compila pero no muestra nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238773/java-se-compila-pero-no-muestra-nada)

Comment: Tu programa funciona, como te dicen es tema de la compilación o ejecución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ejecutar el codigo no hay ningun mensaje pidiendo que se digite un numero. tambien el codigo nunca se detiene debido a que los intentos no tienen limite. sigues descontando 1 en cada ciclo pero la cuenta continua aun con numeros negativos, por lo que debes agregar una condicion mas en el while.

Prueba con este codigo:

```
public class Exercise1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero, aleatorio;
        int intentos = 5;
        aleatorio = (short)(100*Math.random()+1);
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");

        do{
            numero = entrada.nextInt();
            if(aleatorio<numero){
               intentos--;
               System.out.println("El numero es mayor. Quedan "+intentos);
            }

            else{
                intentos--;
                System.out.println("El numero es menor. Quedan "+intentos);
            }
        }
        while(numero != aleatorio&& intentos>0);
        System.out.println("Ganaste");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

quizás esta pregunta pueda ayudarte:
[java se compila pero no muestra nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238773/java-se-compila-pero-no-muestra-nada?rq=1)

Recuerda que tienes que compilar (usando el comando javac) y luego ejecutar el programa (usando el comando java).

Saludos